# how to use multiple images in django ecommerce

Tags: python, django

so basically i can explain my query this way

that
for example when we open amazon.com we open a product we see a primary image (which is the image of the Product) but sidewise we also see seperate images which are of same product but defines different aspects

again clearer example :
i open a bag in amazon.com
it initially shows black color of back but i am a psycho and want a different color and so there are photos of that same product but in different color in same page thats what i am talking about...
i need those pics in my project how do i do

btw in django only

i tried creating a different model but couldnt figure out

Comment: Did you try to have a FK to a image model ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok first create a new model and lets call it Image and it will contain the following data:

```
class Image(models.Model):
   product = models.ForigenKey(Product)
   image = models.ImageField()
   is_primary = models.BooleanField()
   color = models.CharField(choices=ColorsEnumClass)
```

**Explain**:

**is_primary**: indicate the the main image of the product

**color**: its an Enum value of the colors in the system and you could link each image with its own color.